# Table compression on 500GB table using Enterprise edition with online=on

Tags: sql-server-2016, table, compression

I am using MS SQL2016 enterprise edition and we have several tables that need to be compressed to save memory and backup space. Right now they are each around 500GB and I am trying to get some space to do test runs, but unfortunately we are not able to try this out. My question is first - I was thinking of using the Online=On option to allow the table to still be used while the compressing is happening, but how will that effect the backup? We have diff occurring 2x daily and a backup, with the table so large I imagine it will take days not hours to use the online approach. What have other done in this case, bit the bullet and take the table offline for 1.5 days over a weekend?

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with everything sepupic said, especially reinforcing the fact you won't be saving space on backups if you're using standard compressed backups anyways.

I also wanted to specifically add you aren't guaranteed to save **Memory** either. Compression is a way to save space on **Disk**. When the data is loaded into **Memory** from a compressed table, it may first use **CPU** to decompress the data before loading it into **Memory**. Visa-versa when writing to a compressed Table as well (the **CPU** runs the compression algorithm on the decompressed data in **Memory** and hardens it to the compressed data on **Disk**). (This isn't always the case though, and in some cases it does stay compressed in **Memory** as well.)

Basically data compression is great for reducing how much **Disk** space is being consumed by a particular Table, and it helps reduce I/O bottlenecks from the **Disk** itself (which is usually the slowest piece of the hardware pie). That's about it for its main uses.

You can read more about this in this great article [Compression And Its Effects On Performance](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/01/sql-performance/compression-effect-on-performance).

Comment: Do you have a reference for your statement regarding lack of savings in memory?  Everything I've found and read says the opposite (that data stays compressed in memory and you see benefits that way as well). - https://community.relativity.com/s/news/aAZ1T000000CqYjWAK/an-introduction-to-sql-server-data-compression

Comment: @JonathanFite You're right, I learned something new. In some cases it does stay compressed in **Memory** but that's not always the case. I've updated my answer to reflect that, and will need to do more research later to understand when one case happens over the other. I'll update my answer again with more information once I'm done researching.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should estimate the compression savings:
[sp_estimate_data_compression_savings (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-estimate-data-compression-savings-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

It can turned out that your table has no gain with `compression` as the greatest part of it is `varbinary(max)` pictures, for example (it's only example, I hope your table can gain from compression)

To use or not to use `online` option depends on how intensively your table is used.

You should prepare at least as much free space in your db as the estimated new size is, as the new copy of your table will be created. It's important to grow your data file prior that you start the rebuild.

You should prepare `log space` also. How much log space is needed depends on your database `recovery model` and on online/offline option. The online rebuild will be `fully logged` in any recovery model, the offline rebuild can be `minimally logged` in simple and bulk logged modes. If you opt for fully logged operation you need twice of your new table size in the transaction log as the space is also need to be reserved for possible rollback.

As for backup size: if you use `compressed` backups now, after you compress some tables the backup size still remain nearly the same.

Comment: I ran the sp_estimate and will be saving 280GB, I already grew the database by 130GB in prep work. We are not compressing the backups right now due to a policy we currently have, I am working on changing that as well. We have already added CPUs for the compression.